# Counting number of instructions executed by a binary using pin, perf and valgrind

Tags: c, assembly, valgrind, x86-64, perf

I am new to **pin** tool which is used for dynamic binary instrumentation. I was trying to write some simple client programs using pin tool API. One such simple client is counting the number of executed instruction of a binary which is given as one of the examples of pin.
I wrote a very basic program in C,

```
int main(){return 0;}
```

and compiled using the gcc compiler. when I use the pin tool to count the instructions used for the binary of the above C program it gave me the answer **96072**
When I used **valgrind** to do the same task it gave me the answer of **97487** which is nearly equal to the previous one. But when I used **perf** the answer is **421,256**
What would be the reason for this discrepancy among various tools?
To find more details I have compiled the C program into a x86 assembly and it consists about 20-30 lines of assembly instructions, But when I used **objdump** to disassemble the binary it was result in a 200-300 lines of assembly instructions. I was not able to figure out the reason for this difference too.
I am running 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04 with the Linux kernel version 3.8.0-39. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When I used valgrind to do the same task it gave me the answer of 97487 which is nearly 
>   equal to the previous one. But when I used perf the answer is 421,256. 
>   What would be the reason
>   for this discrepancy among various tools?

My guess is that `perf` gives you both user *and* kernel mode instructions (this is the default). Please try

```
    perf stat -e instructions:u your_executable
```

which is supposed to count only instructions executed in user mode. More details in the [perf tutorial](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Options_controlling_event_selection).

> To find more details I have compiled the C program into a x86 assembly
>   and it consists about 20-30 lines of assembly instructions, But when I
>   used objdump to disassemble the binary it was result in a 200-300
>   lines of assembly instructions. I was not able to figure out the 
>   reason for this difference too.

In the first case you only get the assembly instructions *exclusively for your code*. In the second case you get all the instructions contained in the executable. Please compile

```
    int main() { }
```

and run `objdump -d name_of_the_executable`. As you will see, many things happen before the `main()` is executed; and after `main()` has finished, a clean-up is executed.

[Linux x86 Program Start Up or - How the heck do we get to main()?](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html)  seems like a nice tutorial.

Comment: Hello, When I do  'perf stat -e instructions:u python MyPythonApp.py' on my python application it gives 0 instructions, Why do you think it may be? Thanks

Comment: Update: Also it gives 0 instructions for a CPP application.

Comment: @mozcelikors I have no idea, sorry. It is also hopeless for me to figure it out since that command works on my machine. Please post a new question, saying that the command is supposed to work, but for some reason, it doesn't work on *your* machine. Maybe someone else can give you hints.

Comment: Thanks for kind and quick reply. I'm using a Virtual Machine now, maybe it works on a real machine?

Comment: @mozcelikors Yes, it might be the problem. Please try it on a real machine.